# Are out-parameters out-dated?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

My intuition and practice for a long time has been to avoid out params if at all possible. I believe that a function should have one logical purpose and that *usually* implies one return type (not returning multiple things). Sometimes, returning multiple things is desirable (f.e. std::map::insert). I know this can be done as a pair/tuple or as output params; the argument of which of those to use is less important to me.

What are the conceptual, design, or performance reasons to prefer either output parameters or return values?

Comment: as I think, that your function might return dictionary of values or object of returned values. for example, if you compute division, you may like to know some things about this operation like bool_value, int_value, float_value and etc. But also you may like to know string_value or exception_value and so on.

Comment: To those voting to close: I'm not asking where to put the space, before or after the `*`. Best practices along the lines of this question should have concrete reasons justifying them, and should be indisputable by reasonable minded people. That's my $0.02 anyway...

Answer (score 6):

You're right, out parameters are not really needed as RVO makes returning by value feasible, even with large types. And having to return multiple things is either a code smell, or can be sensibly packed in a structure.

I'd say the only remaining reason, and it's a biggie, is **consistency**. If the class already has tens of methods returning by parameter, stick to it (unless you have the liberty to refactor the darn thing :).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'code smell' part? Specifically, why is it?  I'm meeting resistance about this practice and my intuition and poorly articulated design reasons apparently aren't convincing arguments :)

Comment: @Dave it depends on the situation. If you want to take up the task to refactor existing code, pro arguments won't cut it, because, frankly, they aren't good enough. Changing something that works is riskier than making the change just for the code to look prettier. By "code smell" I mean it probably could have been implemented in a cleaner way (that's why it depends on the situation).

Comment: `it probably could have been implemented in a cleaner way`: Why is using out params (often) indicative of poor/unclean implementation (or design)?

Comment: @Dave it's often a sign that two-phase construction is required and that's horrid. If you're doing something like appending to a container then an out parameter is fine and probably the sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, a third alternative might be to pass a callback. The callback might have multiple methods if the called function "produces" multiple values.

Though a function that takes a callback argument doesn't really fit the definition of a "function", neither does a function that returns multiple values, IMO.